# Pid 4845 in trap loop, signal 11 Memory fault(coredump)

Tags: gdb

We are facing an error when running proccess

```
Pid 4845 in trap loop, signal 11
Memory fault(coredump)
```

Here the output of the command gdb bch core

```
bscs2app:/apps/bscsadm/bscs/SK_20200202 ] gdb bch core
HP gdb 6.3 for HP Itanium (32 or 64 bit) and target HP-UX 11iv2 and 11iv3.
Copyright 1986 - 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
Hewlett-Packard Wildebeest 6.3 (based on GDB) is covered by the
GNU General Public License. Type "show copying" to see the conditions to
change it and/or distribute copies. Type "show warranty" for warranty/support.
..
warning: Load module /apps/bscsadm/bscs/bin/hpux11_31.x/bch has been stripped.  
Debugging information is not available.

(no debugging symbols found)...
Core was generated by `bch'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
SEGV_MAPERR - Address not mapped to object
(no debugging symbols found)..."/apps/bscsadm/bscs/SK_20200202/./": can't read symbols: File format not recognized.

warning: Error in reading symbols from ... skipping


warning: Load module /oracle/ora111/lib/libnnz11.so has been stripped.  
Debugging information is not available.

#0  0xc0000000000d2120:0 in BV_overlap+0x2e0 ()
   from /usr/lib/hpux64/dld.so
(gdb)
```

Comment: Please consider the emergency of the situation and thanks for your feedback

Comment: Welcome to SO - if it's an emergency, I'd recommend you quickly read [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to provide all of the information that someone might need, well formatted, to be able to answer your question, and make sure it has all of the relevant tags so that people will pick it up. Right now, it seems unlikely to get an answer as you've posted an unformatted blob of messages without much context.

Answer (score 1):

If installing the latest [HP-UX Linker, Libraries and Tools](https://myenterpriselicense.hpe.com/cwp-ui/free-software/HPUX-Linker) patch does not solve your problem, you should report it to HPE.